# How to animate this imported character in Unity?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I imported a zombie character asset from the unity store and it came with one animator controller and two animation scripts. I already have my movement script attached to my zombie player and it moves when I press the arrow keys. I want it to do the run animation while it goes forward.

I added the animator component to my player and fed it with the animator controller which came with the asset. But when I click play I only see the idle standing animation and not the running one. do I need to use additional scripts?

Comment: Have the controller the condition for the backward button? like idle-(backward pressed)>run

Comment: here are the scripts: http://pastebin.com/VqrJzUtk
http://pastebin.com/ykuyzhA1

Comment: the update method is empty, how you call the method run when the movements buttons are pressed?

Comment: so how do i make it trigger the run animation when i press the move keys? using the update method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the methods in the Update method, something like this:

```
void Update() {
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("W")||Input.GetButtonDown("S")){
        Run();
    }else{
        OtherIdle();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using input

You need to:
 1. Detect input every frame (so in your `Update()` method).
 2. Call the method`Run()` to set the animation bool to true.

This will make the Run animation play when the "w" key is pressed if the Animator Controller is set up properly:

```
void Update () {

    // If the forward key is pressed...
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("w")){

        // Play the Run animation
        Run();
    }
}
```

### Using speed

Alternatively you could give a new parameter to your animation controller "speed" and set the bool for the animation to play when speed is above a certain value. Else if the speed is below the value, play the Idle animation. This way, if you have a Walk animation, you can play it when the speed is between running speed and stationary.